# Wordpress left column - sidebar

Tags: wordpress, display

I've never run civi under Wordpress - (many times under Drupal and Joomla) and know NOTHING about Wordpress themes.
How do I get it to look like the demo site ie no wp-admin menu and the Civicrm left column with recent contacts , new contact Etc.

Comment: Please include your versions of both CiviCRM and Wordpress.  Also please indicate what research you have done to try to solve this problem for yourself. This site is designed to help people who have tried to solve the problem themselves, but haven't been able to.  "know NOTHING about Wordpress themes" suggests you have made no attempt to sort things out for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is simply a missing feature in CiviCRM for WordPress.  The left-hand menu is collapsible, but it's necessary for navigating the backend.

It would be nice to have the recent contacts and quick-add button somewhere, but it'll have to be within the main real estate of CiviCRM on the backend in WordPress.